# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: fails to get called after a while

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a project where the rotation events stop firing after removing/adding a lot of view/viewControllers. It works for a while and then at random the new view added to the window never gets shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: called.

The status bar fails to rotate as well but the view/view controller functions normal (minus rotation). Also there is only one view / viewController added to the window at a time. I'm assuming a old viewController is registered as key but everything added to window is a subclass of view controller and none of the subclasses are showing up in instrument allocations except the active one.

Is there a way on the app delegate or window to find which view controller is key?

Is there any other reason why the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: could be failing to get called?

Each view controller is implementing:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
```

(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return YES;
    }

```
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) 
                     interfaceOrientation duration: (NSTimeInterval) duration {
    //manual rotation code
}
```

Here is the code I'm using in the application delegate to change the root view controller and the displayed  view.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:new.view 
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                animations:^{
                    //add new view
                    [self.window addSubview:new.view];

                    //play transition animation for old and new views
                    new.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(new.view.transform, newEnd);
                    old.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(old.view.transform, oldEnd);

                    //if old view is a "modal style" then keep it in front on new view
                    if([old conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PreloadableModalView)]) {
                        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:old.view];
                    }

                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    //remove old view
                    [old removeSubviews];
                    [old.view removeFromSuperview];
                }];
```

Comment: ViewControllers are not "key" - a single window is key for the application.  You do not add viewControllers to a window - you add views.  How do you know shouldAutoRotate is not called?

Comment: I'm am passing the view [window addSubview:new.view] not that controller, which will allow the UIWindow to use the nextResponder property of the UIView to find my viewController. [apple's docs on presenting a viewcontroller](http://bit.ly/jrMjE2). The shouldAutorotate is not getting called because I added a NSLog in that function and it never fires. I also added an observer for the autorotate event which does log out but it doesn't help me because the status bar doesn't rotate if I try to run my manual rotation function.[apple's doc on responding to orientation](http://bit.ly/iQTXgk)

Comment: Hmm. Is there a UITabBar involved here (you mention "root view controller")?  In the past I have had to create a custom subclass of UITabBarController, and override it's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation with this:  {  return self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];}  so that the shouldAutoRotate actually gets propagated to the sub view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the root of the problem was that removing the viewController that the window was sending the rotation event during the transition caused the window to sometimes not register the new viewcontroller as the new root.

I just have one UIView (with its own UIViewController) added to the Window. During the animation I was removing the root view controller and adding a new one to the screen. The fix was to switch view controllers before the animation.

1. I created a screenshot of the current view
2. removed the old view controller
3. set the new view controller as the rootviewcontroller and add the view to the window
4. ran the transition animation
5. oncomplete i delete the image

this is the main parts of the code:

```
//create a image of old view and add to window
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(old.view.bounds.size);
[[old.view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *screenshot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:snapshot];
[self.window addSubview:screenshot];
[screenshot release];

//remove view and viewcontroller
[old.view removeFromSuperview];

//set new viewcontroller as root
if(self.window.rootViewController)
    self.window.rootViewController = nil;
self.window.rootViewController = new;

//transition code goes here


//animate
[UIView transitionWithView:new.view 
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                animations:^{

                    //add new view
                    [self.window addSubview:new.view];

                    //play transition animation
                    if(isOldModalDisplay) {
                        screenshot.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(new.view.transform, newEnd);
                        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:screenshot];
                    } else {
                        new.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(new.view.transform, newEnd);
                    }
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    //remove screenshot
                    [screenshot removeFromSuperview];
                }];
```